# When should I use class-only protocol rathar than @objc?

Tags: swift

When we want to limit protocol adoption to class types, we can use `:class` protocol or `@objc` protocol.

But, I fail to see the advantage of "class-only protocol" over `@objc` protocol.

The differences I know:

1. **Size**
   `@objc` is more space efficient.

   ```
   @objc protocol ProtocolObjC {}
   protocol ProtocolClass: class {}

   sizeof(ProtocolObjC)  // -> 8
   sizeof(ProtocolClass) // -> 16
   ```
2. **Checking for Protocol Conformance**
   Only for `@objc` protocol

   ```
   @objc protocol ProtocolObjC {}
   protocol ProtocolClass: class {}

   let obj:AnyObject = NSObject()

   obj is ProtocolObjC  // -> false
   obj is ProtocolClass // < [!] error: cannot downcast from 'AnyObject' to non-@objc protocol type 'ProtocolClass'
   ```
3. **Optional Protocol Requirements**
   Only for `@objc` protocol

   ```
   @objc protocol ProtocolObjC {
       optional func foo()
   }
   protocol ProtocolClass: class {
       optional func foo() // < [!] error: 'optional' can only be applied to members of an @objc protocol
   }
   ```

So, is there any use case where we should use `: class` protocol? or someone know any disadvantages of `@objc`?

---

ADDED: Thanks @Antonio !

```
enum MyEnum { case A,B,C }

@objc protocol ProtoObjC {

    // Generics
    typealias FooType
    var foo:FooType {get set}

    // Tuple
    var bar:(Int,Int) {get set}

    // Enum
    var baz:MyEnum {get set}
}
```

All of them causes compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are 2 different things not to be compared to each other.

My rule of thumb is that native swift protocols should always be used, unless objc compatibility is needed, or unless a certain feature available through @objc only is needed..

However the advantage of using swift protocols is that all swift related features, non available in objc, can be used, such as:

- generics
- tuples
- swift enums

But regardless of that, I'd still stick with swift protocols for a pure stylistic choice.

Comment: I agree "pure stylistic choice" :)